# Beautifulsoup trouble getting nested span elements

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using Python and BS4 and I'm able to grab the top entry from the page, but I'm looking to get all of them.

`cardAttr = soup.find(class_='box_card_attribute').find("span", {"class": False}).text`

`cardAttr = soup.select_one('span.box_card_attribute >span').text`

Both of the above will give me the first iteration, but trying to use `find_all` gives me an AttributeError. Below is a snippet of the HTML.

```
    <div id="card_list" class="list">
                    <div class="t_row c_normal">
                        <div class="box_card_img">
                            <img id="card_image_0_1" alt="Tri-Horned Dragon" title="Tri-Horned Dragon" class="none">
                        </div>
                        <dl class="flex_1">
                            <dd class="box_card_name flex_1 top_set">
                                <span class="card_ruby"></span>
                                <span class="card_name">Tri-Horned Dragon</span>
                            </dd>
                            <dd class="icon flex_1 top_set">
                                <div class="lr_icon rid rid_5" style="background-color:#e86d6d;color:#e86d6d">
                                    <p>SE</p>
                                    <span style="background-color:#fff4f4;border-color:#e86d6d;color:#e86d6d; ">
                                            Secret Rare
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </dd>
                            <dd class="remove_btn top_set">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn hex red"  title="Remove this card from the list.">
                                    <span>X</span>
                                    <input type="hidden" class="lang" value="">
                                    <input type="hidden" class="cid" value="4711">
                                </a>
                            </dd>
                            <dd class="box_card_spec flex_1">
    
                                <span class="box_card_attribute">
                                    <img class="icon_img" src="external/image/parts/attribute/attribute_icon_dark.png" alt="DARK" title="DARK">
                                    <span>DARK</span>
                                </span>
```

Currently I can grab the 'DARK' text, but I can't seem to get it to run through the entirety of the page as I could with `class=card_name`.

If needed this is the url I'm looking at.

https://www.db.yugioh-card.com/yugiohdb/card_search.action?ope=1&sess=1&pid=11101000&rp=99999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all cards titles + their attributes & texts you can use next example:

```py
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.db.yugioh-card.com/yugiohdb/card_search.action?ope=1&sess=1&pid=11101000&rp=99999"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

out = []
for t in soup.select(".t_row"):
    title = t.select_one(".card_name").get_text(strip=True)
    attrs = {
        s["class"][0]: re.sub(r"\s{2,}", "", s.get_text(strip=True))
        for s in t.select(".box_card_spec > span")
    }
    text = t.select_one(".box_card_text").get_text(strip=True)
    out.append({"title": title, **attrs, "text": text})

df = pd.DataFrame(out).fillna("")
print(df.head().to_markdown())
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

|  | title | box_card_attribute | box_card_level_rank | card_info_species_and_other_item | atk_power | def_power | text | box_card_effect |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Tri-Horned Dragon | DARK | Level 8 | [Dragon/Normal] | ATK 2850 | DEF 2350 | An unworthy dragon with three sharp horns sprouting from its head. |  |
| 1 | Blue-Eyes White Dragon | LIGHT | Level 8 | [Dragon/Normal] | ATK 3000 | DEF 2500 | This legendary dragon is a powerful engine of destruction. Virtually invincible, very few have faced this awesome creature and lived to tell the tale. |  |
| 2 | Hitotsu-Me Giant | EARTH | Level 4 | [Beast-Warrior/Normal] | ATK 1200 | DEF 1000 | A one-eyed behemoth with thick, powerful arms made for delivering punishing blows. |  |
| 3 | Flame Swordsman | FIRE | Level 5 | [Warrior/Fusion] | ATK 1800 | DEF 1600 | "Flame Manipulator" + "Masaki the Legendary Swordsman" |  |
| 4 | Skull Servant | DARK | Level 1 | [Zombie/Normal] | ATK 300 | DEF 200 | A skeletal ghost that isn't strong but can mean trouble in large numbers. |  |

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Oddly this is exactly what I was aiming to do so I could keep going with a personal project. I was going about it in a very roundabout way. Thankfully it won't work for the rest, but it'll help me figure it all out with a workflow!